# Glpk java output

Tags: java, io, output, glpk

How can I print all the resolved problem in java-glpk on my console or a file?

Something like this:
(this output comes from gusek)

```
------ ------------    ------------- ------------- -------------
     1 x[1]         *              1             0             1 
     2 x[2]         *              1             0             1 
     3 x[3]         *              0             0             1 
     4 x[4]         *              1             0             1 
     5 x[5]         *              1             0             1 
     6 x[6]         *              1             0             1
```

The listeners (GlpkCallback.addListener(this) and GlpkTerminal.addListener(this)) in my java code just return this:

```
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.55
3 rows, 15440 columns, 46320 non-zeros
15440 integer variables, all of which are binary
Preprocessing...
1 row, 15440 columns, 15440 non-zeros
15440 integer variables, all of which are binary
Scaling...
 A: min|aij| = 5.718e+001  max|aij| = 2.719e+005  ratio = 4.755e+003
GM: min|aij| = 1.000e+000  max|aij| = 1.000e+000  ratio = 1.000e+000
EQ: min|aij| = 1.000e+000  max|aij| = 1.000e+000  ratio = 1.000e+000
2N: min|aij| = 6.701e-001  max|aij| = 1.330e+000  ratio = 1.985e+000
Constructing initial basis...
Size of triangular part is 1
Solving LP relaxation...
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.55
1 row, 15440 columns, 15440 non-zeros
*     0: obj =  1.584183802e+007  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
*   500: obj =  1.190189187e+007  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
*  1000: obj =  1.142465659e+007  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
*  1500: obj =  1.122247777e+007  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
*  1615: obj =  1.121676854e+007  infeas = 0.000e+000 (0)
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
Integer optimization begins...
+  1615: mip =     not found yet >=              -inf        (1; 0)
+  1615: >>>>>  1.121676854e+007 >=  1.121676854e+007   0.0% (1; 0)
Better solution found
+  1615: mip =  1.121676854e+007 >=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 1)
INTEGER OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND
```

Hope someone can help.

Here's my java code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ilucasrds/enok1h5k/3/

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you show two different things.
The Output from your listeners on the one hand, contains all the information provided while the solver is running. The gusek example on the other hand provides the solution after the solver is done.

Depending on what kind of information of the solution you want, the API has four different routines for you:

```
int glp_print_sol(glp_prob *P, const char *fname);
int glp_print_ipt(glp_prob *P, const char *fname);
int glp_print_mip(glp_prob *P, const char *fname);
```

for the KKT-Conditions(simplex/interiorpoint) and the integer feasibility report.

```
int glp_print_ranges(glp prob *P, int len, const int list[], int flags,
const char *fname);
```

Writes the sensitivity analysis report, which is comparable to the gusek output. With the additional len and list[] attributes one can define a more specific set of rows/cols to analyse/output. If len is zero every row/col is analyzed.

For further in code processing of the solution one can also use

```
double glp_get_obj_coef(glp_prob *P, int j);
```

Which will return the objective coefficient of a defined column

Comment: Hello puhgee, the three first commands worked, but when i write the glp print ranges , this error appear: Unexpected type: Required:Value, found: Class.
Heres the code: GLPK.glp_print_ranges(lp, int len, const int list[], int flags, fname);

Comment: Hi there, Try GLPK.glp_print_ranges(lp,0,NULL,0,fname) for output of all cols/rows. The 0 in len will override the list[] which therfor can be NULL.